# What kind of exercises should I do to make hard labor easier/safer?

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training

I live a mostly sedentary life but have recently started doing some work on a farm on the weekends. I'm 30 years old but I'm worried about getting injured moving straight into high-strain work -- shoveling, pulling around wheeled carts, lifting & carrying lumber and bagged goods. Also, I've been getting tired faster than I'd like.

I'd like to exercise during the week to get my body more prepared for the weekends. What sort of exercises would be best to train for the type of hard labor I've described above? I've considered putting two piles of dirt in my backyard and shoveling between the two - it seems like that'd exercise all the relevant muscles. But maybe something like crunches & weights would be better? Should I go to a gym and ask there?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Farmers walk I guess